# Am I calling the wrong ID or class when creating this cube in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a cube with style rules in CSS, and while I have the structure of the cube correct I'm failing to make it apply correctly. I can't determine if I'm just calling the wrong IDs in the structure of the cube.

```css
div#cube {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 180px auto 150px auto;
  position: relative;
  transform: perspective(450px);
}

div.cube_face {
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

div#cube_front {
  transform: translateZ(-50px);
}

div#cube_left {
  transform: translateX(-200px) rotateY(90deg);
}

div#cube_right {
  transform: translateX(200px) rotateY(-90deg);
}

div#cube_top {
  transform: translateY(-200px) rotateX(-90deg);
}

div#cube_bottom {
  transform: translateY(200px) rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<section id="center">
  <div id="cube">
    <div id="cube_bottom" class="cube_face">
      <h1>The 15th Annual Chupacabra Music Festival</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="cube_top" class="cube_face">
      <p>Snow Storm Pilot <span>-</span> Ivory Elephants <span>-</span> Laureen Torres
        <span>-</span> Little Mouse <span>-</span> Sheila G <span>-</span> Tachyon Pulse
        <span>-</span> Falstaff Ergo <span>-</span> The Roes <span>-</span> Porter Dew
        <span>-</span> MLTPLX <span>-</span> Smoke Ring <span>-</span> James Po
        <span>-</span> Kate Belle <span>-</span> Ian Mann <span>-</span> Back to the Front
        <span>-</span> Codfish <span>-</span> The Chromatones <span>-</span> Fiona Bennett
        <span>-</span> Crop Circles <br /> &amp; MORE!!!! </p>
    </div>
    <div id="cube_left" class="cube_face">
      <img src="cf_photo1.png" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div id="cube_right" class="cube_face">
      <img src="cf_photo2.png" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div id="cube_front" class="cube_face">
      <img src="cf_photo3.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've attempted changing the classes I'm calling by doing variations, I'll use cube_front as an example. I've tried div#cube_front, .cube_front, div.cube_front, cube.cube_front, etc. My understanding of IDs and classes may not be up to par either. I appreciate any assistance offered on this problem.

Comment: The rules appear to _apply_ to the elements fine, when inspected via browser dev tools. That it doesn't show as intended - must be due to something in the values you are applying not being right for the intended purpose, I suppose.

Comment: i think `transform: perspective(450px);` is wrong property, it should be `perspective: 450px;`

Answer (score 0):

I think your css code is incorrect for `perspective` property.

It should be `perspective: 450px;`

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/amit7soni/pen/WNywgLV) demo for the same

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was playing with the transform rule with that perspective rule and must've forgot to remove the parenthesis.